# Destructuring state in React render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I see a lot of examples that show a React component that looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {
       foo: 'foo',
       bar: 'bar'
     }
   }

   render() {
     const { foo, bar } = this.state

     return <Text>{foo}{bar}</Text>
   }
}
```

As you can see, the component's state has been destructured. I can see that the JSX looks cleaner, but it appears that it would be harder to know that a variables came from the components state. Is there any benefit of doing this in terms of best practices or is it just a preference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Advantage**: The code looks much cleaner especially if you need to reuse state values multiple times in a component.

**Disadvantage:** If you're making a module or open sourcing your code the destructed statement could cause confusions.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `const { foo, bar } = this.state;` code looks much cleaner if you are using same variables multiple times. In this use case i wouldnt destruct state

Answer (score -1):

it is also easy to create immutable data from source using destructuring

```
 const { foo, bar } = {...this.state}
```