# Not able to add item to list in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My button and function call is as follows:

```
<td>
  <button
    id="home.js"
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-default btn-sm"
    onClick={this._onButtonClickHome}
  >
    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />
  </button>
</td>
```

My React code is:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    idList: ["hi"],
    showComponentHome: false
  };
}

_onButtonClickHome(event) {
  const idhome = event.target.id;
  console.log(idhome);
  this.state.idList.push(idhome);
  console.log(this.state.idList);
  this.setState({
    showComponentHome: true
  });
}
```

I'm not able to ad the id "home.js" to the list idList. Can someone please solve the issue or suggest a better way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

1. Please change the button code to following:

```
<td><button id="home.js" type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={(event) => this._onButtonClickHome(event)}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></td>
```

2. Please auto-bind the function as below:

```
_onButtonClickHome = (event) => {
  // Your code
}
```

3. You cannot push directly to this.state.idList. Make a copy of it.

```
const { idList } = this.state;
```

[This is equivalent to const idList = this.state.idList - Technically called as object destructuring]

4. Now you can push to idList. If you want put it on the state.

```
idList.push("idhome");
```

Comment: You should not mutate state directly by pushing to it.

Comment: `const { idList } = this.state;` does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307735/destructuring-state-in-react-render - it does. :)

Comment: @PavelKratochvil, yes, it is obviously true because `const {array} = objectWithArray` is shorthand for `const array = objectWithArray.array`. It just makes a copy of `objectWithArray.array` in a variable called `array`.

Comment: You are mixing 2 different things. It actually does copy. But copy of reference(pointer to memory) not copy of that array. When you want to keep state immutable copying just reference is simply wrong tho.

Comment: @Avanthika "Please read about object destructuring ... Thanks for the downvote though"? I'm not the one who downvoted. I suggest you adopt a more humble attitude and read up about object destructuring yourself, since your answer is simply not correct. See Jolly's answer for a proper copy of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following:

```
_onButtonClickHome(event) { 
    const idhome = event.target.id;
    const idList = Object.assign([], this.state.idList);

    idList.push(idhome);

    this.setState({idList, showComponentHome: true});
}
```

The problem might be that you are pushing the new element directly using `this.state.idList`, but that's not a good way to update the state. You should create a copy of the current array in the state, update it, and then override the array in the state with the update array.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the framework rules defined in their documentation. For more reading: [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)  section: Using State Correctly. There is point about immutable state.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Solution extends Component {
  state = {
    idList: ["hi"],
    showComponentHome: false
  };

  _onButtonClickHome = (idhome) => {
    console.log(idhome);
    let tempArr = [...this.state.idList, idhome];
    this.setState({ idList: tempArr });
    this.setState({
      showComponentHome: true
    });
    console.log(tempArr);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-default btn-sm"
        onClick={() => this._onButtonClickHome("home.js")}
      >
        Set State
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Solution;
```

I hope it helps.