# Add items to list in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, list

I want to add `multiple` items in my `list` on button click.
My list looks like this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
    this.state = {
        movieData: 
        [
            {
                "MovieID": 1,
                "MovieName": "Iron Man",
                "LeadActor": "Robert Downey Jr.",
                "LeadActress": "Gwyneth Paltrow",
                "YearOfRelease": 2008,
                "Language": "English"
            },
            {
                "MovieID": 2,
                "MovieName": "Iron Man 2",
                "LeadActor": "Robert Downey Jr.",
                "LeadActress": "Gwyneth Paltrow",
                "YearOfRelease": 2010,
                "Language": "English"
            },
            {
                "MovieID": 3,
                "MovieName": "Thor",
                "LeadActor": "Chris Hemsworth",
                "LeadActress": "Natalie Portman",
                "YearOfRelease": 2011,
                "Language": "English"
            }
    ]
};
```

There should be a form with `input` elements that takes values: `id`, `movie name`, `lead actor`, `lead actress`, `year of release`, `language`.

Now, I have found solutions to add item to an array, which is this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    myArray: [...prevState.myArray, 1]
}));
```

But, even with this method, I can add only single item on button click.

How can i add multiple items to my list in this format:

```
{
       "MovieID": some value,
       "MovieName": "some value",
       "LeadActor": "some value",
       "LeadActress": "some value",
       "YearOfRelease": some value,
       "Language": "some value"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to add item to list in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160671/not-able-to-add-item-to-list-in-reactjs)

Comment: `myArray: [...prevState.myArray, ...arrayOfNewItems]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete examples. Here I set a **movie** object to an array **movieData** in state in constructor. In every input field, I bind **handleChange** in **onChange** event and get input from input element to set **movie** object that is available in state. then after submitting form, I push that **movie** object to **movieData** array. Finally I used **MUIDatatable** where I passed movieData to show all movies. Hope it helps you.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

class MultiItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            movieData: [
                {
                    "MovieID": 1,
                    "MovieName": "Iron Man",
                    "LeadActor": "Robert Downey Jr.",
                    "LeadActress": "Gwyneth Paltrow",
                    "YearOfRelease": 2008,
                    "Language": "English"
                }
            ],
            movie: {}
        }
    }

    columns = ["MovieID", "MovieName", "LeadActor", "LeadActress", "YearOfRelease", "Language"];
    options = {
        filterType: "dropdown",
        responsive: "scroll"
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        this.name = e.target.name;
        this.value = e.target.value;
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                movie: {
                    ...prevState.movie,
                    [this.name]: this.value
                }
            }
        });
    };

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let lastMovie = this.state.movieData[this.state.movieData.length -1];

        this.setState(prevState => {
            const movieData = prevState.movieData.concat({...prevState.movie, MovieID: lastMovie.MovieID + 1});
            return {
                movieData,
                movie: {},
            };
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-4'>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="MovieName">Movie Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name='MovieName' value={this.state.movie.MovieName}
                                       onChange={this.handleChange}
                                       className="form-control" id="MovieName"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="LeadActor">Lead Actor</label>
                                <input type="text" name='LeadActor' value={this.state.movie.LeadActor}
                                       onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="LeadActor"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="LeadActor">Lead Actress</label>
                                <input type="text" name='LeadActress' value={this.state.movie.LeadActress}
                                       onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="LeadActress"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="LeadActor">Year Of Release</label>
                                <input type="text" name='YearOfRelease' value={this.state.movie.YearOfRelease}
                                       onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="YearOfRelease"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="LeadActor">Language</label>
                                <input type="text" name='Language' value={this.state.movie.Language}
                                       onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="Language"/>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                        <MUIDataTable
                            title={"Movies"}
                            data={this.state.movieData}
                            columns={this.columns}
                            options={this.options}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MultiItems;
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But I get a warning in the line: `this.state.movie.MovieID = lastMovie.MovieID + 1;`  Warning: `Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()` How can i solve this?

Comment: Hi @AnishArya I have modified that line code and updated here. Please check it. It will not show that warning.

Answer (score 2):

```
setNewState = movies => {
    this.setState({
        // Concats the two arrays into one
        myArray: [...this.state.myArray, ...movies]
    })
}
```

[Reference to spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Above code allows you for concatenating the two arrays into one.

Equal to:

```
setNewState = movies => {
    this.setState({
        // Concats the two arrays into one
        myArray: this.state.myArray.concat(movies)
    })
}
```

[Reference to concat syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)